# Native vs JavaScript API

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-native

Here is a more theoretical question on how to build certain features in an Ionic app:
Ionic Native provides a lot of Plugins to support native features. Some of these features are (meanwhile) also supported by the browsers/JavaScript out-of-the-box (e.g. capture a photo, get Location).
Is there a recommendation which way to go if both approaches are able to achieve the same result?

One concrete scenario that I currently have is the integration of the payment platform Stripe: There is a Ionic Native plugin for that (which is not really up-to-date) and it should also be possible to use the JS library provided by Stripe directly. Which way would you recommend?

Thanks for you thoughts on that!

Comment: Interesting question! Ionic Native plugins might be easier to integrate and tested by the Ionic community, out-of-the-box-solutions might be more up to date and perform better...